# How to run Robot Framework's `robot` command from a shell/bash script on Windows?

Tags: bash, shell, robotframework

As a user I want to execute Robot Framework's `robot` command with some command line options. I put everything in a script to avoid retyping the long command each time - see example below. On Linux an Mac OS I can execute this script from any terminal emulator, i.e.

```
# Linux
. run_local_tests.sh

# Mac OS
./run_local_tests.sh
```

On Windows an application (VSCode Editor) associated with `.sh` file type is opened instead of executing the `robot` command or an error like `robot: command not found` is returned

```
# Windows
.\run_local_tests.sh
# OR
run_local_tests.sh
# OR
bash run_local_tests.sh
```

> shell script - filename: run_local_tests.sh
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> # Set desired loglevel: NONE (less details), INFO, DEBUG, TRACE (most details) 
> export LOG_LEVEL=TRACE
> # RUN CONTRIBUTION SERVICE TESTS
> robot -i CONTRIBUTION -e circleci \
>   --outputdir results \
>   --log NONE \
>   --report NONE \
>   --output XML/CONTRIBUTION.xml \
>   --noncritical not-ready \
>   --flattenkeywords for \
>   --flattenkeywords foritem \
>   --flattenkeywords name:_resources.* \
>   --loglevel $LOG_LEVEL \
>   --name CONTRI \
>   robot/CONTRIBUTION_TESTS/
> ```

- Renaming the script from `.sh` to `.bat`  doen't help :(
- entering `bash`, then activating venv and calling the script doesn't work

What other options are there (**without** installing additional tools like Cygwin etc.)?

Comment: Is the `robot` binary in your PATH? Please check.

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm using a virtualenv (venv)

Comment: Print your PATH before you execute `robot` and see if the PATH really contains the binary. Check for the spelling of `robot`. Maybe it's `robot.exe`.

Comment: As soon as venv is activated (`.\venv\Scripts\activate`) robot is on PATH. When using a .bat file it seems that this can't deal with `\\` for line continuation. I guess there is no other way than writing a complete new and properly formated  .bat file

Comment: Can you do a replacement of the '\' character? Like with `sed`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually trying to answer the same question in the opposite direction (how to trigger/run them on my machine as .sh). Looks like we may help each other out. 8)

I believe this is what you're looking for:
Your file would be **run_local_tests.bat**

Contents:

```
@echo off
cd C:\path\to\robot\project
call robot -d relative/path/to/test/output/dir relative/path/to/run_local_tests.bat
```

Of course you can use any other valid robot cli syntax in the call also. You may have to make it executable too. I'm not sure.

Comment: The `robot` command takes .robot files or path to a folder which contains .robot files. In your example you are passing a .bat file. I think this will not work.

Comment: But this may work: `call robot -d relative/path/to/test/output/dir relative/path/to/tests_dir` or `call robot -d relative/path/to/test/output/dir relative/path/to/example_test.robot`.